# Unable to open python on linux

Tags: python, ubuntu

I know this may be the most silliest questions to be asked but i'm suddenly not able to open python from terminal.
I have python 2.7 installed on ubuntu 14.04 box, but now when i fire python on my command line i get the error

aman@L-JZCHG32:~$ python

The program 'python' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install python-minimal

I have tried reinstalling python

```
sudo dpkg -P python2.7
sudo apt-get install python2.7
```

but it still wont work. Can somebody suggest me what went wrong and how can i correct it.
Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using `python2`?

Comment: Have you tried `sudo apt-get install python` and did you get an error message?  You say you "installed" python but not **how** you installed python.

Comment: Type exactly what the command tells you and then try again.

Comment: yes i have tried sudo apt-get install python. It shows 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 11 not upgraded.

Comment: Are you sure python-minimal is installed? In Ubuntu it divides it out into several packages. You might even try `sudo apt-get install -f` to ensure you do not have any broken packages.

Comment: but even after that that i type python from command line i get The program python is currently not installed

Comment: what do you get with `whereis python`?

Comment: Does /usr/bin/python work?

Comment: tried installing python minimal also, it shows python-minimal is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 11 not upgraded.

Comment: whereis python gives python: /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/python2.7-config /usr/bin/python3.4m /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/python3.4 /etc/python2.7 /etc/python /etc/python3.4 /usr/lib/python2.7 /usr/lib/python3.4 /usr/bin/X11/python2.7 /usr/bin/X11/python2.7-config /usr/bin/X11/python3.4m /usr/bin/X11/python /usr/bin/X11/python3.4 /usr/local/lib/python2.7 /usr/local/lib/python3.4 /usr/include/python2.7 /usr/share/python /opt/python3.4/bin/python3.4m /opt/python3.4/bin/python3.4-config /opt/python3.4/bin/python3.4m-config /opt/python3.4/bin/python3.4 /usr/share/man/man1/python.1.gz

Comment: then please list the output of `ls -l /usr/bin/python`

Comment: output for ls -l /usr/bin/python is lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 18 Apr  7 18:07 /usr/bin/python -> /usr/lib/python2.7

Comment: ...and what messages do you get with `/usr/bin/python` and `/usr/lib/python2.7`?

Comment: bash: /usr/lib/python2.7: Is a directory

Answer (score 0):

It seems you've probably corrupted your PATH variable. Try `/usr/bin/python` in the terminal. If that works, you'll need to fix your PATH variable.

A quick fix would be export `PATH=/usr/bin:$PATH` but there's probably something not quite right with the whole path variable at the moment, which would be worth further examining.

Comment: In my .bashrc file i added PATH=/usr/bin:$PATH at the end

Comment: But it still shows python not installed when trying to open python from command line

Comment: Did you try starting python via /usr/bin/python from the terminal already?